# round float to integer

Tags: php

how can i round a float e.g
(0.001) to 1
(12.321) to 13
(12.011) to 13
(19.999) to 20
PS: if the float is 12.000 i dont want it to round like 12 only.

```
round(12.001,0);
```

i tried a lot of example except this but can't acheive my results.
your help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/ceil ?

Comment: round doesn't work that way. for what you're trying to achieve use `ceil` instead of `round`. `ceil` returns the next int value if is higher than 12.000 for example, but round only if it's highter than 12.500.

Comment: literally you saved me. :)

Comment: feeling so dumb i actually spent an hour and couldn't think of floor and ceil. thank you alot.

Answer (score 1):

Try Ceil

[ceil($number)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php): round up